# Creating random numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Dear respected coders,

I have a question regarding my code which is not working. Actually, I want to generate random numbers which should be presented in a list, whenever I call the function. Could someone please help me clarifying what goes wrong here and how to continue? I am a bit confused right now.

This is the error message I got:

```
TypeError: RandomNumbers() missing 1 required positional` argument: 'Number'
```

I understand, but I do not want to enter a number, it should output me a random list consisting of 7 elements with elements varying between 0 and 9. For example:
[2,3,5,0,2,0,9)

```
import random
Number = []

def RandomNumbers(Number):
    for i in range(0,7):
        x = Number.randint(0,9)
        Number.append(x)
        print(Number)

RandomNumbers()
```

Comment: your `def RandomNumbers(Number):`takes one argument  but you are not giving one when calling `RandomNumbers()`

Comment: you need to write `RandomNumbers(Number)`. you forgot to pass the list

Comment: You don't really need a function for this as you can easily use a list comprehension as follows:- *Number = [random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(7)]*

Comment: You're also calling `Number.randint()` when you should be calling `random.randint()`.

Comment: Just my opinion, but the salutation in the question is unnecessary (it's generally implied in any case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you've mentioned that you do not want to input any numbers, change your Python function declaration to not take in any arguments - `Number` in this case - as it currently expects one.

You also need to replace `x = Number.randint(0,9)` with `x = random.randint(0,9)` as `randint` is a method belonging to `random`.

This should do what you want:

```
import random
Number = []

def RandomNumbers():
    for i in range(0,7):
        x = random.randint(0,9)
        Number.append(x)
    print(Number)

RandomNumbers()
```

Output:

`[1, 7, 6, 5, 5, 7, 5]`

---

There's also a smaller, cleaner solution, which achieves the same output as above using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import random
Number = [random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(7)]

print(Number)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. When I try this, I get an output in the form of a tree.                               [8]
[8, 0]
[8, 0, 9]
[8, 0, 9, 5]
[8, 0, 9, 5, 7]
[8, 0, 9, 5, 7, 0]
[8, 0, 9, 5, 7, 0, 4]                             Actually I only want one list containing of 7 elements.

Comment: @AbishaBindar Answer modified, does that help?

Comment: Yes, it helps definitely. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

just replace the last line of code

```
RandomNumbers()
```

with

```
RandomNumbers(ANYNUMBER)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a function that receives object without it. so you could do this:

```
import random
Number = []

def RandomNumbers():
    for i in range(0,7):
        x = random.randint(0,9)
        Number.append(x)
    return Number

print(RandomNumbers())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `Number.randint` to `random.randint`. The corrected code looks like that:

```
import random
Number = []

def RandomNumbers(Number):
    for i in range(0,7):
        x = random.randint(0,9)
        Number.append(x)
        print(Number)

RandomNumbers(Number)
```

Output:

```
[9]
[9, 1]
[9, 1, 5]
[9, 1, 5, 8]
[9, 1, 5, 8, 3]
[9, 1, 5, 8, 3, 9]
[9, 1, 5, 8, 3, 9, 2]
```

But this code is not cleaned up at all. You can instead learn about the module `numpy` which has great functions including creating arrays with random integers!

Comment: numpy for this problem is **extremely overkill**.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def RandomNumbers():
    arr = []
    for i in range(0,7):
        x = random.randint(0,9)
        arr.append(x)
    return(arr)

Number = RandomNumbers()
print(Number)
```

Use random.randint(0,9) instead of Number.randint(0,9)
You probably want to use this function more than once so it is advisable to declare an array inside the function.